# Graph API - Check if user has Full access to Office 365 Planner Task

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

Using graph API we requested oauth access token for planner task, I received the access token successfully. The token list the scopes as below

`Calendars.ReadWrite Contacts.ReadWrite Directory.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All Notes.ReadWrite People.Read **Tasks.ReadWrite** User.Read.All profile openid email`

But when I try to get any planner task, I get a below error.
`GET /groups/{group-id}/planner/plans`

The error is `The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or its temporarily unavailable`

Is it possible to identify the resources that the user has access to in his account? Is there any graph API that could list the resources for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks.ReadWrite is not for Planner, but you have Group.ReadWrite.All, which is the right permission, so the issue is no about the scopes.

Reading the tasks of a Plan within a Group requires the caller to be a member of the group. Being an owner will not work.

There is no single API that can give you all the Plans a user can access. The best available method is to [list the groups that the user is a member of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-getmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), and [get the list of plans in each group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/plannergroup-list-plans?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).